# Let $A\in$ $M_{2015x2015}$ prove that $A^2-A\neq I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in$ $M_{2015x2015}(\mathbb{R})$ prove that $A^2-A\neq I$

*Hint:* Show that $A$ does not have eigenvalues over $\mathbb{R}$ if $A^2-A = I$

Thanks

Comment: Could the downvoters provide a short explanation so I could edit properly?

Comment: I didn't downvote but my guess is that you just stated this as "do this problem for me" without showing any kind of effort whatsoever. I have to say though that 4 downvotes seem like an overraction, especially to a new user

Comment: @Ovi Thank you, will pay more attention next time.

Comment: @Tamir Why next time? You already indicated that you are aware of the fact that you can [edit]. So why not edit the question to include your thoughts/efforts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A diagonal matrix with $\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$'s on the diagonal is a counterexample.